# Removing a function for Safari ONLY in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I've created a single page website and I've used **JQuery** to create a **ScrollTo** effect when clicking on different links. Because I have a fixed div at the top of the page, I've offset the target to the height of the fixed div at the top of the page, so that when it scrolls, the contents isn't hidden by the fixed div at the top of the page:

```
if ($target) {
     var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - $("#div_at_top_of_page").outerHeight();
```

This works fine, scrolling the target div below my fixed navigation at the top of my page. However in Safari, the scroll to already scrolls below the div by default, so adding:

```
$("#div_at_top_of_page").outerHeight();
```

this causes Safari to scroll to the target, but also adding the height of the div at the top of the page, creating a margin.

I'm just looking for a solution to cancel this:

```
$("#div_at_top_of_page").outerHeight()
```

for Safari only. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: I'm open to any other solutions rather than browser detection.

Here's the complete thing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 function filterPath(string) {
 return string
 .replace(/^\//,'')
 .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
 .replace(/\/$/,'');
    }
$('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
 if ( filterPath(location.pathname) == filterPath(this.pathname)
 && location.hostname == this.hostname
 && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
  var $targetId = $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor :    false;
   if ($target) {
     var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - $("#fixed_div_at_top").outerHeight();
     $(this).click(function(e) {
       $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 800);
       e.preventDefault();
       var d = document.createElement();
    d.style.height = "101%";
    d.style.overflow = "hidden";
    document.body.appendChild(d);
    window.scrollTo(0,scrollToM);
    setTimeout(function() {
    d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
        }, 10);
       return false;
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: Um, wouldn't it simply be easier to fix a container div below your fixed top div and do all your scrolling within that, instead of trying to browser detect?

Comment: You might try setting up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with HTML and your Javascript for people to play with.

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question is to use `$.browser` (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/ -- deprecated long ago and removed in jQuery 1.9), but I can't recommend it. Better to use feature detection.  Even better not to rely on either method.  Have provided this as an answer only because you initially asked specifically about targeting Safari.

Comment: I've tried to use that, but I'm struggling to correctly code this as I'm a newbie when it comes to Javascript. The fixed div below the top div idea is confusing me, I'm not understanding how this would work.

Comment: `$.browser` was removed in jQuery 1.9.

Comment: @MattBurland, yes, I probably should have specified the reasons I wouldn't recommend it.  That's one of them.  Feature detection is almost always the correct way to go instead of browser detection, but I'm not convinced either is the best approach here. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I've searched for a solution for this everywhere, that's why I've decided to post my question here. Thanks for the help anyhow, all is appreciated.

Comment: @DanMountford, if you post your html, I can probably help you further, but I might not be able to get to it until tomorrow.

Comment: @Derek I've found a solution by altering my div arrangement. Thanks for the help anyhow :).